# Async function not returning database query data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying firebase for a specific document with the following properties:

```
name: 'Bob',
price: '12',
description: 'My favorite food is ice cream',
quantity: '5',
```

I then want to set my state variables `name`, `price`, `description`, and `quantity` to each respective property value.

However, when I run my `useEffect`, the values aren't set to the variables--my console log prints `undefined` for each variables.

I think there may be something wrong with my async function. Any ideas?

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      // grab document id from URL
      const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      const pid = params.get("pid");
      setPidString(pid);
      console.log(pid);

      // query firebase db
      const docRef = db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection("products")
        .doc(`${pid}`);

      //query for specific document
      docRef
        .get()
        .then(function (doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            async function fetchProductData() {
              const productData = await doc.data();
              console.log(productData);

              setName(doc.data().name);
              setPrice(doc.data().price);
              setDescription(doc.data().description);
              setQuantity(doc.data().quantity);
              setDownloaded(true);
              console.log("MY NAME", name);
              console.log("MY DESCRIPTION", description);
              console.log("MY PRICE", price);
              console.log("MY QUANTITY", quantity);
            }
            fetchProductData();
          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error getting product data:", error);
        });
    } else {
      setProducts("");
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Comment: You haven't called setState anywhere here.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi Doug, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I'm calling setName, setPrice, etc inside of the function. Why would I need setState?

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question show your setstate hook, because we can't see any of those functions.  We don't have any assurance that you're doing it correctly.  Quesitons should contain enough information so that anyone can copy it and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this `doc.data().someProperty` it should be `productData.someProperty` every time. The result of your `await doc.data();` is in the `productData` variable.

Then you are also logging undefined variables. Those variables aren't declared and you aren't assigning anything to them.

```
console.log("MY NAME", name);
console.log("MY DESCRIPTION", description);
console.log("MY PRICE", price);
console.log("MY QUANTITY", quantity);
```

You should log the properties of the object where the data is stored.

```
console.log("MY NAME", productData.name);
console.log("MY DESCRIPTION", productData.description);
console.log("MY PRICE", productData.price);
console.log("MY QUANTITY", productData.quantity);
```

Logging the state wouldn't work either since nothing guarantees you that the component's state will be updated immediatly upon calling setState.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Looks like there is still something wrong with my async function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  async function fetchProductData() {
      const doc1 = await docRef.get();
      if(!doc1.exists){
        console.log('No such document!');

      }
      else{
          const productData =  doc.data();
          console.log(productData);
          setName(doc.data().name);
          setPrice(doc.data().price);
          setDescription(doc.data().description);
          setQuantity(doc.data().quantity);
          setDownloaded(true);
          console.log("MY NAME", name);
          console.log("MY DESCRIPTION", description);
          console.log("MY PRICE", price);
          console.log("MY QUANTITY", quantity);
        }
    }
    fetchProductData();
```